# Filtering files using os.walk()

Tags: python

I'm looking to modify the program to print the contents of any file called log.txt in a given year's subdirectory, ignoring any other file.

```
import os

year = input('Enter year: ')
path = os.path.join('logs', year)
print()
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    print(dirname, 'contains subdirectories:', subdirs, end=' ')
    print('and the files:', files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do. I won't provide the complete code:

1. Iterate over `files` and check for `'log.txt'`.
2. Get the path to the file. Hint: `os.path.join`.
3. `open` the file and `read` it.
4. print out the content